# python 3 How to append number to number

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

How would I append a number to the end of another number?

for example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = a + b
print(a)
Output = 3
```

I want to get my output as 12 but instead I get 3. I understand that when you do number + number you get the addition of that but I would like to do is append b to a and so I would get 12. I have tried appending a number to a number but I get an error. I think that you can only append a list.

My question is:
**How do I append a number to a number?**

or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I tried turning it into a string first and then back in to a integer but I must have done it wrong. p.s. type that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get 3 is because a and b contain integers. What you want is string concatenation to get 12. In order to use string concatenation you need strings. You can type cast the integers to string using `str()` and then use `int()` to type cast the string to an integer.

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = str(a) + str(b)
a = int(a)
print(a)
```

The oneliner solution is already provided in the comments.